# Multiple dom tags are re-generated when `setState`

Tags: reactjs, performance

```
class Calendar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selected: null,
    }
  }

  generate = () => {
    console.log('generate');
    let tags = [];
    for(let i = 0; i<31; i++){
      tags.push(<div key={i} className={this.state.selected === (i+1) ? 'selected' : ''}>{i+1}</div>);
    }
    return tags;
  }

  clickHandle = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      selected: e.target.innerText
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div onClick={this.clickHandle}>
        {this.generate()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

When I click `div`, it calls `generate()`.

I think it is inefficient.

Is there any more efficient way to generate multiple elements from the above code?

**Condition**

1. When I click one `div`, it has to get the class `selected`.
2. When I click another `div`, previous clicked `div` has to remove the class `selected` and 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find two issues here that preventing the desired result.
When you use values from DOM, you always get a string. Since you are using '===', it is never evaluating to true and hence the className does not change.

```
clickHandle = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      selected: parseInt(e.target.innerText, 10)
    })
  }
```

You should also use key when using repetitive elements, to improve performance.

```
generate = () => {
    console.log('generate');
    let tags = [];
    for(let i = 0; i<31; i++){
      tags.push(<div key={'keyname'+i} className={this.state.selected === (i+1) ? 'selected' : ''}>{i+1}</div>);
    }
    return tags;
  }
```

Comment: that above code is instant. I want to know how to avoid re calling `generate()` if I can.

Comment: in my Real code. I used Key attribute and parseInt.

Answer (score 0):

You should give each div a [unique key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html). This helps React only re-render the divs that actually have changes, whilst the other divs that haven't changed will just get reused.

```
let tags = [];
for(let i = 0; i<31; i++){
  tags.push(<div key={i} className={this.state.selected === (i+1) ? 'selected' : ''}>{i+1}</div>);
}
return tags;
```

Comment: I know I have to put key attribute. above code is instant code. I just want to know avoid re calling `generate()` if I can.

Comment: As in giving the key to the divs means that the generate function won't have to rerender all the divs, only the ones that have changed. Unless your generate function is doing something intensive, i.e. making an API call for every div, there's no real difference in using the generate function vs. hardcoding all X divs in the render method since that'd get called on state change anyway. If it is doing something intensive then there may be ways to make it more efficient

Comment: @usee3893820 oh.... Thanks a lot. I think I need to learn about it more..